# What herbs would be effective in Pizza dough?

Tags: dough, pizza, herbs

I have had very good luck making pizza dough in my bread maker and have started adding some spices such as chilli flakes and italian seasoning in the dough itself. I can taste the heat from the chilli flakes, I dont really taste much from the Italian seasoning. Are there any other spices anyone recommends?

Comment: Herbs sprinkled on pulled and oiled dough usually work much better

Comment: @suhaim, Sorry, but this question as it stands isn't a good fit.  It fails to meet the requirement of having an objective answer as worded.  If you wanted to know why the chili flakes worked and the Italian seasonings didn't and let that inform your choices for other things to try, it would work much better.

Comment: Please also see the meta thread, [Should "what can I add to X" questions be closed by default?](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/q/1091) which lists several options for rephrasing the question in a more constructive form. If you have some definable end result in mind that's more than just personal preference, that would be a good question to ask.

Answer (score 2):

You could try flavoured oils instead; I have oregano and garlic infused olive oil (that I usually use on salads or on risotto).

If you insist on fresh/dried I'd try thyme and/or rosemary. Give them a good chopping/bashing before hand to release thier oils and flavour.